# C++/SDL "initial value of reference to a non-const must be an lvalue"

Tags: c++, sdl

i have a player class in which i have a function to return a SDL_Rect for the dimensions and the position of my player object:

```
SDL_Rect Player::pos() 
{
    return SDL_Rect { mPosX, mPosY, PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT };
}
```

When i use this in my main program to render the player with:

```
Renderer::Draw(img, player.pos(), NULL, angle);
```

i get the error: "initial value of reference to a non-const must be an lvalue"
but when i instead write:

```
SDL_Rect pos = player.pos();
Renderer::Draw(img, pos, NULL, angle);
```

it works.
Why cant i use player.pos() directly and have to use another SLD_Rect variable?

Comment: Short answer: Because lvalue references cannot bind rvalues.

Comment: Is there a way to use it this way without always create another variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Renderer::Draw` declares to modify its second argument (otherwise it would be const and you wouldnt get that error), if you pass a temporary then modifying the argument is pointless and it is most likely an error, thats why it is forbidden.

Consider this example:

```
int foo() { return 3; }
void bar(int& x) { ++x; }
void moo(const int& x) {}

int main() {
    bar(foo()); // not allowed
    moo(foo()); // ok     

    int x = foo(); 
    bar(x);     // ok, modifies x
}
```

If `bar(foo())` would be allowed, nothing super bad would happen. On the other hand there is no reason to allow it. `bar` explicitly declares that it wants to modify its argument so why allow to pass something when you have no way to observe that modification?

**PS**: If you think this answer is too handwavy, may I refer you to the comment by @DanielLangr:

> Short answer: Because lvalue references cannot bind rvalues.

Comment: I changed the second argument from Renderer::Draw to const then it works. Renderer::Draw doesn't modify the second argument - my bad thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Dentho in my experience too much `const` doesnt hurt but too little does. Imho its a good rule of thumb to declare everything `const` by default and only when you know it needs to be non-const remove it

Comment: @Dentho for completeness I added a `moo(const int&)` to the example